# About sets with finite measure on intersection with compact set

Tags: measure-theory

On page 74 of this [lecture note](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math285/ts-gmt.pdf), the author say it is evident that

> For $M = \cup^{\infty}_{j=1} M_j$, we have
> $$\mathcal{H}^n(M_j \cap K) < \infty \text{ for each } M_j \text{ and compact }K$$
> is equivalent to the existence of a positive $\mathcal{H}^n$-measurable function $\theta$ on $M$ that $$\int_{M\cap K} \theta\; d\mathcal{H}^n < \infty$$

All of the sets above are in an ambient Euclidean space.
My question is:

1. With the given $\theta$ we can use Lusin theorem to show $\mathcal{H}^n(M_j \cap K) < \infty$, but I am not sure if this is overkill.
2. How to show the other direction, namely the existence of $\theta$ ?

Comment: You are missing some hypothesis on $\theta$. Obviously finiteness of the integral for $\theta \equiv 0$ does not give finiteness of $\mathcal H^{n} (M_j \cap K)$.

Comment: Sorry I forget the assumption $\theta >0$, I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint  for 2): Choose $\theta = \sum a_j E_j$ where $E_1=M_1, E_2=M_2\setminus M_1$ , $E_l=M_l\setminus (M_1\cup M_2,\cdots \cup M_{l-1})$ for $l >2$. Choose $a_n$'s appropriately.

Comment: Won't the choice of $a_j$ depends on $K$? At first sight $\int_{M \cap K} \theta\;  d\mathcal{H}^n = \sum a_j \mathcal{H}^n(M_j \cap K)$ (say $M_j$ are pairwise-disjoint for example) so we need at least $a_j\mathcal{H}^n(M_j \cap K) \to 0$.

Comment: @MathTheNovice Take $a_j=1$ if $\mathcal H^{n}(E_j)=0$ and $a_j =\frac 1 {2^{j} \mathcal H^{n}(E_j)}$ otherwise. Use the fact that $\mathcal H^{n}(E_j\cap K) \leq \mathcal H^{n}(M_j)$ whatever $K$ is.